# How to start a process using a .dll file in VC++ 2010

Tags: c++, file, dll, process

I am trying to learn how to use DLL file in C++. According to my research, this should open notepad when I use the DisplayNotepad() in my code. I am trying to compile it but I am getting compiler errors and I know for a fact windows.h defines ShellExecute but it says identifier not found. here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
extern "C"
{
__declspec(dllexport) void DisplayNotepad()
 {
     ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "c:\\windows\\notepad.exe", NULL,NULL, SW_SHOW);
 }
}
```

My compiler is giving me the following error: error C3861: 'ShellExecute': identifier not found. Am I doing this completely wrong? Thanks for the input.

Comment: the fact that this code runs in a DLL isn't really relevant. Let's abstract that out of your question. The question is about the `ShellExecute` system call.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The declaration of `ShellExecute` is [found in Shellapi.h](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), not windows.h.

Answer (score 2):

Shell headers are not included by default. Always include the header listed in the documentation (in this case `shellapi.h`).